# Интересное значение слова "крепость" в контексте

Tags: значение-слов

Помогите разобраться, что имеется ввиду под словом **крепость** в следующем предложении:

> Эти площадные подьячие писали в своей писчей избушке **всякие крепости** и посторонние письма.
>
> Источник: [Чтения и рассказы по истории России](https://books.google.ru/books?id=sMwYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT323&lpg=PT323&dq=%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0.&source=bl&ots=S1XOS7AqP_&sig=txl2fAlrkR0UVnBlHTbToxnYJP4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDx_m_1t3eAhUPposKHYK1DzAQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0.&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

В словаре Ефремовой:
[кре́пость](https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
**3.** *ж.* Документ, подтверждающий право на владение какой-либо собственностью.

В словаре Ушакова:
III. КРЕ́ПОСТЬ, крепости, мн. крепости, крепостей, *жен.* (офиц. *дорев.*). Документ о праве на владение чем-нибудь. **Совершать крепость на дом. Купчая крепость.**

248. *А которые люди в селех и в деревнях грамоте не умеют: и им в таких не в больших делех велеть на себя такия крепости писать иных сел земским, или церковным дьячком, или кому нибудь, и к тем крепостям велети в свое место прикладывать руки отцем своим духовным, или кому в том они верят сторонним людем.*
     [Полное Собрание законов Российской империи. Собрание Первое](https://books.google.ee/books?id=PFqdDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=4sga4O7TLC&sig=C3xsAC9XfFuhd5ecWU-Xk002eNQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf-tjj2N3eAhVBh6YKHRSvCbAQ6AEwDXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false)